Limit (upper and lower) of sequence of sets
In a certain exercise I have been asked to find the lower and upper limits of the set sequence given by $A_n = \{a_1, a_2\}$ if $n$ is even and $A_n = \{a_3\}$ if $n$ is odd. I don't have much control over these concepts.

As far as I know and as I have read in another question here in MSE, since $\lim \inf A_n = \bigcup_{k \geq 1} \bigcap_{n \geq k} A_n$, this limite would be the set that is in $A_1 \cap A_2\cap A_3\dots$ or in $A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \dots$, this is, that is in the intersection of any of the sets but with the exception of a finitely intersection of ones. Given this, the intersection at the same time of any odd and even term would be the empty set, so that would be the lower limit. However, I'm not sure if $A_2 \cap A_4 \cap A_6 \dots$ would also be a valid intersection, since in that case the limit set is $\{a_1, a_2 \}$.

Could somebody help me? Besides, could anyone explain me the same but with upper limit? Btw, $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{R}, a_i \not= a_j, i \not= j$.

For a fixed $k$, what is $\bigcap_{n\geqslant k}A_n$? Then what do you get when taking the union of those sets for all $k$?
There is a similar formula for $\lim\sup$, you'll have to answer 1. what is $\bigcup_{n\geqslant k}A_k$ and 2. what is the union of all those sets?
You're almost there!

For example, if $k = 3$, then the expression would be $A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 \dots$. What I was wondering is if the intersection need to be of consecutive $A_n$'s or you can choose arbitrary ones.

Yes, your $A_n$'s are consecutive! For $k=3$, $\bigcap_{n\geqslant 3}A_n=A_3\cap A_4 \cap A_5\cap\dots\subset A_3\cap A_4={a_3}\cap{a_1,a_2}=\emptyset$. Show that it holds for every $k$, and then you will be able to compute the union. Same thing for the $\lim\sup$.
(by the way, in my last comment, 2. is "what is the intersection of all those sets")

Thanks for your answer
